# how to make session_start change on each refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

Im currently using the below code on my wordpress to display posts randomly but not duplicate them. This works apart from when I refresh the page it stays the same as it is. The only way to change what is displayed is to clear my cache and cookie. Is it possible to make it so that on each refresh it changes?

Here is my code:

```
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: Don't use a session. If you don't want the variable to persist, there is no need to store it in a session.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `if` condition, in current situation - `rand` option set only if the session is empty. So that it working at first time i.e session not set.

```
  $seed = rand();
  $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
```

instead of

```
if (empty($seed)) {
  $seed = rand();
  $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain to OP why? "Do this" is handy but doesn't necessarily provide understanding to the question-er.

Comment: This caused it to break by removing that, as it now duplicates the posts.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out like

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
echo session_id();
```

This returns you with unique session ids on each refresh

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how would i go about implementing the regenerate with my code?  Sorry im very new to sessions.